# How to deploy multiple instances of an APP on a iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, deployment

I have a iOS APP program with bundle named "com.ignet.test". For testing reason, I want to make several instances of this APP on a iPhone device. How to deploy that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to achieve this is to go with **multiple bundle identifiers**.
For example:

```
com.ignet.test1
com.ignet.test2
com.ignet.test3
```

This way you can use independent bundle identifiers and multiple app versions can run in parallel on the same device. Here is a nice [tutorial](http://nilsou.com/blog/2013/07/29/how-to-have-two-versions-of-the-same-app-on-your-device/) that describes how to do this.